# Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long after upgrage to LightSwitch v2

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have upgraded my Lightswitch app from v1 to v2 and when I select a Menu, some of the screens return the following error:

[image]

It seems that some of the URL string request Silverlight makes to the server are too long.

On another Menu I also get the following same error but in VS 2012.  This is generated code part of the LightSwitchApplication namespace.

[image]

I have the same error in browser or desktop mode.

Using newly released VS 2012 with SQL Server

**UPDATE (08/21/2012):**
New test done:
I have created a completely new Lightswitch Project in VS 2012, added only **one** SQL Database table (SQL Server 2008 R2) to the project, created a simple search screen of that table and I have the same error.

This table contains 36 Columns

**UPDATE (08/22/2012):**
I have found what is causing the error.  I have an SQL row (nvarchar(MAX)) which contains 80,289 characters.  It is an xml string value from a Telerik Rich Text Box which is not used anymore from this implementation [Here](http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/48/Using-the-Telerik-Rich-Text-Editor-In-Visual-Studio-LightSwitch.aspx).  It is now simply a stored string.  If I convert the SQL data type to XML instead of nvarchar(MAX), the LS page now works.  Since I have opened a forum discussion on Microsoft Lightswitch forum as well, I will now switch over [there](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/e10b6569-efd3-447a-8b17-0e3bcbd3ae78/) to get an answer on this behavior. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Did you do a rebuild All?
2) Do you have this project deep in your file system? What I do is put the project in a short directoy path like "C:\temp" to see if that is the problem.

Comment: 1) yes, no avail  2) no, in normal projects folder.  See my edit in the post, did a test with only one table.  I have to say I have alot of foreign keys in it, at least ten.  I will make a test with a new database, same table with no joins.

Comment: Just did a test with no joins and it is working.  I will revert with more findings.

Answer (score 0):

If Michael's suggestion doesn't help, it could also be the number of properties in the table that are marked as "Display By Default". You could try unckecking the box for any properties that don't need to be displayed (this also affects searches).

Comment: I removed all "Display By Default" except for four columns and it did not work.